# Eclipse Oxygen undo/redo not working

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

**Edit:** After installing Oxygen 1.a via zip file everything works normally.

I just set up Eclipse Oxygen on a new laptop, and I've found that the undo/redo features aren't properly working. Whenever I write or delete a line of code it does not come up as a clickable button in the menu, nor do the shortcuts for it work. I am using the following version, and I am on Windows 10.

Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Build id: 20171218-0600

Comment: did you try ctrl+z (undo) and ctrl+y (redo) ?

Comment: @LorenzoCanavaggio Yes, it doesn't work either.

Comment: look at .log file, may be there's a shortcut conflict.

Comment: If you go to **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys** and enter **undo** in the field containing "_type filter text_" what do you see in the **Binding** field?